# scp only files with defined extension

Tags: shell, scp

I want to transfer only files with special extensions (like only *.tar.gz, *.war) in one scp command (Debian Linux). Is this possible, if yes how is the syntax?

Should be someting like:

```
scp 192.168.1.2:/srv/myfiles/'*.tar.gz *.war' .
```

But this is not working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This absolutely is possible

```
scp 192.168.1.2:/srv/myfiles/\{*.tar.gz,*.war\} .
```

Comment: This works, but it's asking for that password twice.

Comment: Ah yes, I'm using keys, so I don't get prompted at all. Answer modified the above should only ask for the password once.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ ssh 33 ls \{\*.log,\*.py\}
engine.log
install.log
parser_lex.py


$ scp 33:\{\*.log,\*.py\} /tmp/
engine.log                                                                                                                   100%   45     0.0KB/s   00:00    
install.log                                                                                                                  100%   18KB  18.0KB/s   00:00    
parser_lex.py                                                                                                                100% 2600     2.5KB/s   00:00
```

Comment: You can also use ssh and tar...

Comment: PS: You can learn how it works while creating a ForceCommand on remote host and check what is in SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND environment variable :) See https://blogs.oracle.com/janp/entry/how_the_scp_protocol_works